# How does UIControl handle continuous touch events differently to UIView?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have a `UIScrollView` which contains multiple child objects (each of which can be considered as a  `UIView` frame containing a vertical slider with plenty of margin) stacked horizontally. If I try to horizontally pan my `UIScrollView`, I want it to scroll as you would expect a `UIScrollView` to do. If I attempt to vertically pan my slider, I want only the slider to move - as long as I have my finger on the screen, the slider should take precedence and the `UIScrollView` should not be able to pan.

If my custom slider object inherits from `UIControl`, everything works out-of-the-box exactly as desired. However, if my custom slider object inherits from `UIView`, I can only vertically pan my slider as long as I move my finger completely vertically - the moment I introduce any horizontal movement, the gesture is stolen by the `UIScrollView` instead and the slider loses focus.

What behaviour does `UIControl` have that `UIView` does not?